# How is NODE_ENV set in OpenShift?

Tags: express, openshift

I've read of the [dangers of not having NODE_ENV properly set in Express](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2015/07/22/the-drastic-effects-of-omitting-node_env-in-your-express-js-applications/). In my OpenShift app, I can display NODE_ENV through a simple Express route and a `console.log` statement, but I can't see it anywhere else, e.g. with the `env` command at the SSH prompy. How/where is it set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mine (and this differs from what you might [find in the documentation](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/63-mean)), it's set in a file at nodejs/configuration/node.env in the gear. To reach it, you can use the cloud console tools -  *rhc ssh -a your-app-name*. In that file, you should see something like

```
#This file specifies the environment to setup prior to running Node.
...
#  Default script name used is server.js
export node_app=server.js
#Any arguments to pass to the application or script.
export node_app_args=""

#Any command line options to pass to Node.
#E.g. export node_opts="--stack-size=2048 --trace_gc"

export node_opts=""
...
#Node production mode turned on by default
export NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-"production"}
```

...which also lets you set up other configuration options. Hope that helps, it took a bit of searching when I first had to do it.

Comment: how did you find it?

Comment: Had to grep for it - _grep -r NODE_ENV ./_